# Regex/PHP: How to remove linebreaks from within a special pattern

Tags: php, regex, line-breaks

i got another problem removing linebreaks from within a token in a template file - the template i have to parse could look something like this:

```
<html>
<style>
body { color: black }
div {
   background-color:#fff; 
}
 <!-- i need to remove the line breaks within {_WP_token[*]} for parsing //-->
<h4>{_WP_token[id="42";class="foo"; style="border:4px solid 
green;padding:20px"; onclick="(this.value=confirm('foo'));"]}</h4>

<script>
    function() {
        console.log('my foo is my castle');
    }
</script>
```

I tried myself without making the break-through. i just succeeded in creating a greedy one, which eats up the first half of the token - here it is:

```
preg_replace("/(\{_(.*?)(.*\s))/ix", "[LB REMOVED]", $htmlTemplate);
```

returns

```
<html>
<style>
body { color: black }
div {
    background-color:#fff; 
}
<!-- it just ate up the first half of my token ! //-->
<h4>[LB_REMOVED]green;padding:20px"; onclick="(this.value=confirm('foo'));"]}</h4>
<script>
function() {
   console.log('my foo is my castle');
}
</script>
```

i made a fiddle here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2EZ

thank you very much in advance.

best regards,
Lupo

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$newString = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","[LB_REMOVED]", $originalString);
```

Comment: but i only want to remove the linebreaks within this special pattern: "{_[A-Za-z]\[* (...ONLY_REMOVE_LINEBREAKS_FROM_THIS_PART...) \]\}"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you correctly. If you want to change

```
<h4>{_WP_token[id="42";class="foo"; style="border:4px solid 
green;padding:20px"; onclick="(this.value=confirm('foo'));"]}</h4>
```

into

```
<h4>{_WP_token[id="42";class="foo"; style="border:4px solid green;padding:20px"; onclick="(this.value=confirm('foo'));"]}</h4>
```

Then you can use this

```
\{_(.*)[\r\n]+
```

and replace with $1, [See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?37mnq)

```
preg_replace("/\{_(.*)[\r\n]+/", "$1", $htmlTemplate);
```

I removed all your modifiers, since you do not use them. [See Modifiers doc](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)